# how do I solve this error: 'RefVariable' object does not support item assignment?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a code in torch and I have to change it to keras but when I do this for the following code it produces this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 3, in 
>       jpe[channel]=mask
>
> TypeError: 'RefVariable' object does not support item assignment

I think this error is for assignment, but I do not know how can I solve it. the main code in torch was:

```
yuv_keep_weighs=(25,9,9)
requested_shape=(100,100)
jpeg_mask=None    
if jpeg_mask is None or requested_shape > jpeg_mask.shape[1:]:
            jpeg_mask = torch.empty((3,) + requested_shape)
            for channel, weights_to_keep in enumerate(yuv_keep_weighs):
                mask = torch.from_numpy(get_jpeg_yuv_filter_mask(requested_shape, 8, weights_to_keep))
                jpeg_mask[channel] = mask
```

I changed it

```
yuv_keep_weighs=(25,9,9)
requested_shape=(100,100)
jpeg_mask=None    
if jpeg_mask is None or requested_shape > jpeg_mask.shape[1:]:
            jpeg_mask = K.zeros((3,) + requested_shape)
            for channel, weights_to_keep in enumerate(yuv_keep_weighs):
                mask = K.variable(get_jpeg_yuv_filter_mask(requested_shape, 8, weights_to_keep))
                jpeg_mask[channel] = mask
```

but the last line produces the error and I do not know how can I do assignment in tensorflow? please, guide me about this issue.

Comment: See the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54899974/error-in-equating-subtensor-in-tensorflow/54900460#54900460

Comment: but I am working in keras. does it work?

Comment: it suggested sth in tensorflow and I do not have feed or session.run:(