# one-hot encoding issue

Tags: arrays, tensorflow

I have the following code which i am trying to achieve one hot encoding.

```
k=tf.Variable(tf.zeros((10,1)))
hprev=tf.Variable(tf.zeros((10,1)))
x=tf.placeholder(tf.int32,shape=None,name="x")
y_op =tf.assign(k, k[x,0].assign(1))
M_c=tf.concat((hprev,y_op),axis=0)
init=tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    print(sess.run(y_op,feed_dict={x:1}))
    print(M_c.eval())
```

I get the error:You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'x_64' with dtype int32. Yet I have passed 1 as the value, which in my understanding is an integer. What I am doing wrong ?. I am still a beginner please.

Comment: tensorflow tensors are immutable. If you want ot change the value of a tensor, you need to create a new tensor for the previous one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow: How to modify the value in tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37071788/tensorflow-how-to-modify-the-value-in-tensor)

Comment: I think this answer will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54899974/error-in-equating-subtensor-in-tensorflow/54900460#54900460